# Anyone successfully installed openfire OR any xmpp server on mac os x lion?

Tags: installation, osx-lion, ejabberd, openfire

I'm trying to install openfire.  It's just a package and should be brain dead simple. The setup wizard invariably fails after you assign an admin username and password.  The failure is that the login username and/or password is incorrect.

Ejabberd won't work on Lion either; the post installation scripts don't work.

If anyone can point me to clear and verified directions, please let me know.  I've wasted a day on this and while I'm not an expert, I do think that I can follow directions well.

Thanks

Comment: My apologies. I got openfire to install under Mac OS X Lion.

It seems obvious in retrospect, but this may help others since I somehow missed the following:

    Download the .dmg and install it. When you finish installing it, nothing happens. It's natural to go, what the ? --AT THIS POINT, I'd just go ahead and reboot. Some have said that you need to reboot once.

Comment: After the reboot, go to System Preferences and look. There will be an openfire pref pane installed. Open that.
    Try to bring up the admin console. (You should start openfire if it isn't already running, also in the same dialog box). You will be run through a wizard the first time. The part I got stuck on was the username and password.
    Your username is admin. That's not negotiable. Enter a valid email address. This email address IS NOT YOUR USERNAME. I kept entering admin@example.com, my real email, everything. Then when I tried to log in I kept using that as my username.

Comment: Repeat, username is "admin". Your password needs to beat least 5 characters long.
    Now you can log in :>

Answer (score 0):

Java is not installed on Lion by default. Start "Java Preferences" app and install Java.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd work in lion (10.7 +)  via [mac ports](http://www.macports.org/)  simply do:

```
$ port install ejabberd
```